# Как включить экран при push уведомлении?

Tags: java, android, firebase, push

Проблема в следующем. Есть push уведомления через firebase, хочу включить экран. Нашел решение, но оно не работает. Что я делаю не так?

В AndroidManifest.xml включены следующие разрешения:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DEVICE_POWER" />
```

В классе MyFirebaseMessegingService extends FirebaseMessagingService

Вызывается onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)

И там в свою очередь я пытаюсь включать экран следующим образом

```
// Turn on the screen for notification
        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        boolean result= Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH&&powerManager.isInteractive()|| Build.VERSION.SDK_INT< Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH&&powerManager.isScreenOn();

        if (!result){
            PowerManager.WakeLock wl = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK |PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE,"MH24_SCREENLOCK");
            wl.acquire(10000);
            PowerManager.WakeLock wl_cpu = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,"MH24_SCREENLOCK");
            wl_cpu.acquire(10000);
        }
```

Остальной листинг кода:

```
sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

            if (/* Check if data needs to be processed by long running job */ true) {
                // For long-running tasks (10 seconds or more) use Firebase Job Dispatcher.

            } else {
                // Handle message within 10 seconds

            }

        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.

    }




    /**
     * Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of
     * the previous token had been compromised. Note that this is called when the InstanceID token
     * is initially generated so this is where you would retrieve the token.
     */
    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String token) {

        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + token);

        // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
        // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
        // Instance ID token to your app server.

    }

    private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        String channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                        .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.fcm_message))
                        .setContentText(messageBody)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                    "Channel human readable title",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```